# memory usage more than 100%

Tags: linux, memory-management, arm

I am using arm processor and one qt based gui application.
There is an issue of slow process.

Mem: 36272K used, 24692K free, 0K shrd, 188K buff, 19544K cached

CPU:  6.1% usr  1.3% sys  0.0% nic 92.4% idle  0.0% io  0.0% irq  0.0% sirq

Load average: 0.25 0.18 0.07 1/43 553

PID  : 512
PPID : 1
USER : root
STAT : S
VSZ  : 62368
%MEM : 102.0
CPU  : 0
%CPU  : 5.5
COMMAND : ./gopaljeearm -qws -nomouse

This is status when i use top command.

Comment: Probably your process is consuming more virtual memory than there is available RAM, so is swapping... Read about [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice answer for Android applications which in turn should be applicable for most of the Linux applications. Quoting...

> Note that memory usage on modern operating systems like Linux is an
>   extremely complicated and difficult to understand area. In fact the
>   chances of you actually correctly interpreting whatever numbers you
>   get is extremely low.

you can read rest of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2299813/1163019).

Another nice read is [ELC: How much memory are applications really using?](http://lwn.net/Articles/230975/) from LWN.